# footer view not displayed in listview (Custom adapter)

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading, adapter, android-arrayadapter

Footer view is not displayed at the end of the listview .
Pleas tell me where I am going wrong .The code for the footerview is :

```
footerView = ((LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
        list.addFooterView(footerView);

        footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
```

Entire Code :

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=20/json";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    static ListView list;
    static LazyAdapter adapter;

    HashMap<String, String> map;

    public static  String message_receiver_str;

    public static int deleteposition;
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;

    View footerView ;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);





     songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);


        try {
            JSONObject arr2 = json.getJSONObject("feed");
            JSONArray arr = arr2.getJSONArray("entry");

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject e1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONArray arr3 = e1.getJSONArray("im:image");

                JSONObject arr8 = e1.getJSONObject("im:name");

                JSONObject arr10 = e1.getJSONObject("im:artist");

                    JSONObject e12 = arr3.getJSONObject(0);

            // creating new HashMap
             map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,  e12.getString("label"));

            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, arr8.getString("label"));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, arr10.getString("label"));
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Network communication error!", 5).show();
        }


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                     int position, long id) {

                                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                                HashMap<String, String> o= (HashMap<String, String>) list.getItemAtPosition(position);

                           //   Toast.makeText(CustomizedListView.this, "ID '" + o.get("title") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

                                deleteposition=position;
                             message_receiver_str= o.get("title");
                             Intent ii= new Intent(getBaseContext(),openedmsg.class); 
                                startActivity(ii);

            }
        });     





        footerView = ((LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
        list.addFooterView(footerView);

        footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

    }   
}
```

LazyAdapter.java

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 


   public static HashMap<String, String> song;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
         return data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

         song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
        artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
        duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

listfooter.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="13dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Tap to Load"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must call `addFooterView()` before you call `setAdapter()` on the `ListView`. Same applies for `addHeaderView()`.